# Understanding synchronized on listeners notifiers

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have singleton thread class that sometimes calls function below and notifies listeners from it's thread `run()` method :

```
public class Serial implements Runnable
{
    private ArrayList observers = new ArrayList();
    ...

    public void run()
    {
    notifyListeners(new CS());
    }

    public synchronized void notifyListeners(CS value)
    {
        log.debug("notifying listeners with Control ");
        int os = observers.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); i++)
            {
                MListener observer = (MListener) observers.get(i);
                observer.dataReceived(value);
            }
    }
    ...

    public void addListener(MListener lsn)
    {
    observers.add(lsn);
    }

    public void removeListener(MListener lsn)
    {
    observers.remove(lsn);
    }


}
```

I'm just wondering what gives `synchronized` on `notifyListeners` method? One of reasons - not allow add/remove observers from/to `ArrayList observers` while `notifyListeners` is called. Please correct me if I'm wrong. What more it might give?

UPD

I have updated my code with two methods `addListener` and `removeListener`. I suppose it is mistake since both of these methods are not `synchronized` and might be called from another thread ?

Comment: I recommend looking at the [multicaster pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEventMulticaster.html), which guarantees non-interference during event delivery without the need for copying the listener list nor synchronizing the whole operation. It’s far more efficient, especially for small numbers of listeners. Look at [its source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/AWTEventMulticaster.java#AWTEventMulticaster) to find out, how to implement it for other event/listener types…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer mostly depends on your context because it could be for 2 potential reasons:

1. We want to protect your list of listeners from concurrent accesses and modifications because it is an `ArrayList` which is not thread-safe (assuming that that the list can be modified elsewhere in your code and any time it is modified it is protected by a `synchronized` block with `this` as object's monitor otherwise it would not be done properly and/or it would be useless).
2. We want to prevent concurrent notifications for some internal logic.

In your case as you only have one thread that calls `notifyListeners` #2 should not be the reason unless the code owner assumed that you could have several threads doing this task in the future.

The reason #1 makes sense only if the list of observers can be modified by other threads concurrently if it is not possible you can simply remove the keyword `synchronized` from your method declaration as it would be useless so it would affect the performances for nothing.

Assuming that #1 is the reason, you should rather use the thread-safe `List` [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead of an `ArrayList` because it is very efficient in mostly read accesses scenarios which is generally the case of a list of observers that we mostly read and rarely modify, your code would then be something like that:

```
public class Serial implements Runnable {
    private final List<MListener> observers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    ...
    public void notifyListeners(CS value) {
        log.debug("notifying listeners with Control ");
        for (MListener observer : observers) {
            observer.dataReceived(value);
        }
    }
```

---

> I suppose it is mistake since both of these methods are not
>   `synchronized` and might be called from another thread ?

I confirm that the current code is not correct since your list of `observers` can be modified by concurrent threads thanks to the `public` methods `addListener` and `removeListener` and those methods don't modify your list within a `synchronized` block with `this` as object's monitor such that **the current code is not thread-safe** as it doesn't prevent concurrent accesses to your non thread-safe list.

Comment: I have updated my code with two methods addListener and removeListener. I suppose it is mistake since both of these methods are not synchronized and might be called from another thread ?

Answer (score 1):

IMO the synchronization on notify does not make sense. If I understand you correctly, the notify method is only called by your singleton thread.

But your observer implementations content probably might be accessed by different threads. There the access to internal state must be synchronized.

E.g. if you want to save the given value to a member of the observer, which later is used by e.g. the main GUI thread you must synchronize the access to this member:

```
// called by your notify thread
void dataReceived( CS value)
{
    synchronized (this)
    {
        myValue = value;
    }
}
```

and:

```
// called by your GUI main thread:
public CS getValue()
{
    synchronized (this)
    {
        // optional check for not null:
        if ( myValue == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
        logger.debug( "returning value: " + myValue);
        return myValue;
    }
}
```

If the CS is an AtomicXY (e.g. AtomicInteger) class, the synchronization is not needed. But if you want to do more than just assigning/returning the value (e.g. some checking or log output) the synchronization is mandatory.

Comment: Of course you are right. I typed this directly here in without support of an IDE. I will correct it.

Comment: Why would you write it that way? Putting the synchronized on the method declaration is the same as the way you have it, except it will show up in the method signature.

Comment: @matt: You are right, in this example it would have the same effect. Two reasons for doing it like that: 1. maybe you have other code in the method which is not needed to be synchronized. 2. Instead of this you can use another monitor especially used for synchronizing the access to the myValue member (e.g. private myValueAccessSemaphore = new Object()). And one could argue that also the fact you mentioned ("show up in the method signature") is another reason for not using it. In fact you want to synchronize the access to myValue and not a whole method.